# Getting variable passed from PHP to JS on Click event, returns all elements variable, not just the one that's clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a WP code, but my problem in specific to JS. So I post my question here at StackOverflow.
Final goal is, clicking on the post image, showing the HTML markup of large img on Console. Here's my code:

```
<div class="img lightbox-trigger">              
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <div class="hover" >
        <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
    </div><!--hover-->
</div><!-- .img .lightbox-trigger -->

<?php $large_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large') ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".lightbox-trigger").click(function(){
            var largeThumb = <?php echo json_encode( $large_thumb ); ?>;
             console.log( largeThumb );
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when I click on one of the post's images, the `largeThumb` value of all other posts (there are 10 posts) printed on Console!

I don't know how to use `$(this)` in this specific context to just get the value related to the element being clicked on.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $(this) is a special variable that contains a reference to the current object,In your example to retrieve the contents of **.lightbox-trigger**, you can do this  `$(this).html();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `data-*` attributes to store the `$large_thumb` of every `lightbox-trigger` in the related `div` :

```
<div class="img lightbox-trigger" data-large-thumb='<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large'); ?>'>              
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <div class="hover" >
        <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
    </div><!--hover-->
</div><!-- .img .lightbox-trigger -->
```

Then in the js you could get this info :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".lightbox-trigger").click(function(){
         console.log( $(this).data('large-thumb') );
         console.log( $(this).html() );
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.